# How can I customize the Login UI (external providers) when using Visual Studio 2013 OWIN Security

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, authentication, customization, owin

I want to customize the `OpenAuthProviders` UI that comes with the **VS2013** web forms new project template so that it shows **Facebook, Google, Twitter, Microsoft Live** brand-images instead of text buttons. I will accept an answer that provides relevant details even if it pertains to the MVC5 template. In the web forms template, the UI user-control has a `ListView` that gets populated by way of this server method:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> GetProviderNames()
    {
        return Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes().Select(t => t.AuthenticationType);
    }
```

where the property, `AuthenticationType`, is the textual name of the provider, e.g. **Google** or **Facebook**. It would be great if the `Select()` could return the brand-logo-images.

My first foray checked into the `Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)`, where the external providers are configured, e.g. `app.UseFacebookAuthentication(..)`.  However I do not see how to provide the brand-logo-images src-url that could be selected in the server method.

If I were to hack this, I would modify the `GetProviderNames()` method where for each `AuthenticationType` a lookup is done to get the image src-url that could be used to populate the attributes of an image element in the UI html.  I just wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT with new link: This question/answer might help: [Custom icon question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769141/asp-net-identity-external-authentication-provider-custom-icon/19777196#19777196)

Comment: Thanks. However that blog does not apply as it refers to a different API, OAuthWebSecurity that was introduced with SimpleMembership in VS2012. I am asking how-to for Microsoft.Owin.Security with Asp.Net.Identity in VS2013.

Comment: Oops, this question/answer might help